# why does this prove concavity?

Tags: convex-analysis

Here is a problem about proving concavity of a function

> Problem 5. Assume $f$ and $g$ are concave. prove that $f+g$  is concave
>
> Answer:
>
> [image]

**How does this prove concavity? I am used to the idea that a function is concave iff $f''\leq 0$.  I don't see how this relation proves concavity.**

Comment: Your definitions are equivalent. This one is the standard definition. You might want to draw the function to see it.

Comment: The definition of concave used is the standard one, which does not assume twice-differentiability. Of course, if you want to define concavity as $f'' \leq 0$, then the problem is very trivial: $f'' \leq 0$ and $g'' \leq 0$ implies $(f+g)'' = f'' + g'' \leq 0$.

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit Equivalent... for $\mathcal{C}^2$ functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is concave if lies above the chord between any two points on it: that is, for any $x,y$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$,
$$ f(tx+(1-t)y) \geq t f(x) + (1-t) f(y). $$
This is a much more general notion than $f'' \leq 0$, since $f$ may not be twice-differentiable. The former is also defined even if $f$ is not continuous, or in more than one dimension.

If $f$ is once-differentiable, this condition can be proved equivalent to $f'$ being decreasing. If $f$ is also twice-differentiable, you can also show that concave implies that $f'' \leq 0$.